# Getting Redis up an running with ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, command-line, redis

I have installed Redis via gems, but am having a problem getting it started.

Following James Edward Gary II steps http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/setting_up_the_redis_server/

I have:

```
$ sudo gem install ezmobius-redis

Password:
Successfully installed ezmobius-redis-0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ezmobius-redis-0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for ezmobius-redis-0.1...

$ redis-server path/to/redis.conf

-bash: redis-server: command not found
```

Any thoughts as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have done just what you have described in your question, then you are missing redis. *ezmobius-redis* is just a Ruby library that allows connecting to redis. redis itself is a separate piece of software running independently.

If you followed the article you linked and if you especially did this:

```
curl -O http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-1.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf redis-1.0.tar.gz 
cd redis-1.0
make
sudo cp redis-server redis-cli redis-benchmark /usr/local/bin
```

then you have actually installed a very old version of redis into the */usr/local* directory.

If you did this starting the server did not work, then you probably have */usr/local* not in your *PATH*. You can start the server using:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/redis-server path/to/redis.conf
```

However, I would suggest to install the newest version of redis. To do that on OSX you should use homebrew:
- Read this (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) as a guide on how to install homebrew and then do a

```
brew install redis
```

to install the newest version of redis.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to open a new terminal to get the latest path settings.  Try typing "bash" or "xterm &" and typing the redis-server command again.